# How deep should I mock dependencies in unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Consider the following function:

```
def get_api_status(api_client):
    response = api_client.get('/status/')
    return response.content
```

and the test for it:

```
def test_get_api_status():
    mocked_api_client = MagicMock()  # depth 0
    mocked_response = MagicMock()  # depth 1
    mocked_response.status = 'ok'  # depth 1.1
    mocked_api_client.get = MagicMock(return_value=mocked_response)  # depth 0.1
    assert get_api_status(mocked_api_client) == 'ok'
```

The above example is really simple but you can see the pattern. What if the `response.content` would also have method `get_data` which would have the method `get_raw_bytes`? The question is: **"when does code start to smell?"**.

#### My assumptions:

1. Let's say `api_client` is here to reduce coupling. `api_client` in real life is subclassed either `http_client` or `filesystem_client`.
2. `api_client.get` does always return `api_response` which has `.content` attribute.

#### My thoughts:

I suspect the problem is either:

- The example is fine. It's the maximal level of complexity. If `api_response.content` would really have also the method `get_data` and the function `get_api_status` would use it then it should be recognised as wrong design.
- tight coupling between `get_api_status` and the `api_client` abstract - do I need to make one more abstract??

Comment: Needing to mock multiple layers is a sign that your dependency is leaking across the codebase - other code is coupled to an interface you don't own. It suggests a Law of Demeter problem too. Your test double should ideally return something *you own*, a data object you can create easily without lots of mocks.

Comment: Thanks for the "Law of Demeter". I guess then it is the design problem. If I would keep making good design I wouldn't have to mock deep.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO we gave to distinguish between `dependencies` (other code that provides *behavior*) and `Data Transfer Objects / Value Objects` .

#### DTOs

This code primary hold *data* and have at most very simple logic, if at all, and does not have Dependencies (references to code of the other type) themselves.
I would not mock DTOs (like `response` in your example) as well as any collection. DTOs and collections are cheap to construct. And when you need to configure them some levels deep you couldn't come around that by mocking anyway.

#### Dependencies

This is other code that provides *behavior*.
There should be no need to mock Dependencies beyond one level dept. Some times we need to dive one level down because the direct dependency is a factory. If you find that one level down is not enough you might think al little about your design...